# Google Analytics report by section of the website

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics is it possible to report unique pageviews by section or area of the website, where a section or area may contain one or more known pages? For example:

An example might be to show how many unique page views for Menu item A, including all the child pages at different levels where Menu item A is the parent.

Comment: Sounds like you could be asking about content groupings where you could have a content group for all pages that fall under menu A, and another group for all pages under menu B, etc. You can only create a max of 5 content groups though

Comment: @nyuen, you can create 5 content groupings, however each grouping might contain multiple (more than five) groups.